# NU1202: MySql.Data.Entity isn't compatible with monoandroid81

Tags: mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mysql-workbench

I am trying to start my first `Xamarin` project and I got some issue while trying to install the `MySqlEntity NuGet` package.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1202  Package MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.8 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package MySql.Data.Entity 6.10.8 supports: net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)  Refo_T3.Android C:\Users\evyat\source\repos\Refo_T3\Refo_T3\Refo_T3.Android\Refo_T3.Android.csproj  1

I tried this solution: [Xamarin.Android: Package XX is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905545/xamarin-android-package-xx-is-not-compatible-with-monoandroid81-monoandroid-ve)
and I still end up with errors.

---

It's my first application on `Xamarin` platform, I used to code in `.NET` but I decided to test my luck with Xamarin.

I couldn't find any more useful information online and I need your better experience.
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written on the [nuget packages page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/6.10.8), the package is only available for .net framework >= 4.5.2

[image]

So you can't install it for Xamarin Android project only classic desktop .Net Framework applications.

Comment: Thank you magicandre1981 for your response. What does it mean for me? That I can't install that package? Isn't it necessary for the development of an application if I am using MySQL Workbench environment?

Comment: you used the wrong package. You need to [install this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)

Comment: I am on duty, I will check tomorrow and let you know man! I appreciate your help very much!!